# I don't want to document a dataset in my R package

Tags: r, r-package, cran

I'm writing my own package and plan to publish to R CRAN.

And my function will use some data so I create a csv file called "keyboardvalue.csv", this csv file is only for my function, not for the package user, and package user can not access it.

But when I use "Check Package", there is always a warning says  :
Undocumented data sets:
  'keyboardvalue'
All user-level objects in a package should have documentation entries.

The question is, this data is not a user-level data, and I don't want to make a document for it, how could I solve that? The file path of this file is "mypackage/data/keyboardvalue.csv"

Comment: From [R-packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html): If you want to store parsed data, but not make it available to the user, put it in R/sysdata.rda. This is the best place to put data that your functions need. If you want to store raw data, put it in inst/extdata.

Comment: So the file name must be "sysdata.rda"?? Because I put keyboardvalue.rda into R folder, there will be a Note when I  use ckeck pacakge.

Comment: Again from that link: "You can use devtools::use_data() to create this file with the argument internal = TRUE:". rda can contain more than one object

Comment: The problem had been solved, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer myself:

Save my data into `sysdata.rda` and put it in the `R` folder in my package.